# ¿Cómo ir aumentando la secuencia alfanumérica a partir de una secuencia dada?

Tags: c#

Quiero crear una secuencia alfanumérica usando números del 0 al 9 y el abecedario. La secuencia será de 4 caracteres, yo le pido al usuario que indique en qué secuencia empezar y cuántas va crear de la secuencia.

Tengo el siguiente código con el cual obtengo la posición de la secuencia que el usuario me indicó, pero no sé cómo empezar la secuencia a partir de la posición de cada uno de los caracteres o números.

En la variable `string secuenciainiciada="";` guardo la posición de  cada uno de los caracteres que tienen la secuencia que el usuario indicó; en este caso cuando corro el programa me regresa esta posición `11,2,22,9`: a partir de aquí empezará a aumentar en uno.

```
string[] arraynumeros = new string[10] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
string[] arrayletras = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", };
            
int total = 30;
string IniSecuencia = "LCWJ";
int indices;
string secuenciainiciada="";
for (int i = 0; i < IniSecuencia.Length; i++)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(IniSecuencia.Substring(i,1), @"^[0-9]+$"))
    {
        indices = Array.IndexOf(arraynumeros, IniSecuencia.Substring(i, 1));
    }
    else
    {
        indices = Array.IndexOf(arrayletras, IniSecuencia.Substring(i, 1));
    }
    secuenciainiciada += Convert.ToString(indices + ",");

}
```

Este es un ejemplo de la secuencia que me debería regresar si pido 30 secuencias y le indico que inicie en LCWJ, tiene que ir aumentando de uno en uno y siempre de derecha a izquierda.

```
    LCWJ
    LCWK
    LCWL
    LCWM
    LCWN
    LCWO
    LCWP
    LCWQ
    LCWR
    LCWS
    LCWT
    LCWU
    LCWW
    LCWX
    LCWY
    LCWZ
    LCX0
    LCX1
    LCX2
    LCX3
    LCX4
    LCX5
    LCX6
    LCX7
    LCX8
    LCX9
    LCXA
    LCXB
    LCXC
    LCXD
    LCXF
```

Comment: Simple, necesitas obtener el último registro y descomponer (string split quizás), ver si es letra o dígito, y si es dígito -> estás en la última posición, verificas si es 9 y de ser así, le ingresas A. Me late que ya tienes una idea del tema :D

Comment: Sabias que te podes ahorrar todo esto, si usas el string como char, y usas valores ascii para ir de un lado a otro ;)... te lo voy a dejar pensar, si no, te escribo una respuesta....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero es que tu ejemplo de salida está mal, tienes 31 items y no 30, luego te saltas LCWU a LCWW, ahí falta por pasar por LCWV

Después hay que juntar los 2 array en un solo (el de número y de letras), porque si no es un lio.

Lo que tienes es lo mismo que un número en base 36, y una posible solución sea trabajar como tal, pasas a base 10 sumas 1 y pasas a base 36. Creo que esto es poco eficiente para este caso.

Lo que yo propongo es tener un Array con las posiciones de cada letra del string de entrada. Por ejemplo, la entrada es "BA" el array tendría [11,10].
El siguiente número hay que sumar 1 al último item del array, es decir la secuencia sería

- [11,10]
- [11,10+1]
- [11, 10+2]
- y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a 36, ahí sumas 1 al siguiente y reseteas el primero
- [11 + 1, 0]
- [11 +1,1]

(Esta lógica es la que creo que intentabas hacer)

Vamos al código:

1. Creamos una función que reciba el string de entrada y nos retorne una lista de posiciones

```
private static List<int> GetPositions(string base36)
{
    List<int> positions = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0;i < base36.Length; i++)
    {
        positions.Add(letras.IndexOf(base36[i]));
    }
    return positions;
}
```

2. Una función que reciba la lista de posiciones e imprima en pantalla el string

```
private static void PrintPosition(List<int> positions)
{
    foreach(int i in positions)
    {
        Console.Write(letras[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

3. Una función que sume Uno a las posiciones

```
private static List<int> SumaUno(List<int> positions,int index=0)
{
    if (index >= positions.Count)
    {
        positions.Add(0);
    }

    if (positions[positions.Count - 1 - index] == letras.Count - 1)
    {
        positions[positions.Count - 1 - index] = 0;
        return SumaUno(positions, index+1);
    }
    else
    {
        positions[positions.Count - 1 - index]++;
        return positions;
    }
}
```

4. Como usarlo

```
private static List<char> letras = new List<char>(){'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
    'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    int cantidad = 30;
    var l = GetPositions("LCWJ");
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++)
    {
        PrintPosition(l);
        l = SumaUno(l);
    }
}
```

5. (opcional) Todo en una Clase que para eso están

```
internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        Base36 a = new Base36("LCWJ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(++a);
        }

    }

}
public class Base36
{
    private static List<char> letras = new List<char>(){'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
        'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

    private List<int> positions = new List<int>();

    public Base36(string number)
    {
        this.positions = GetPositions(number);
    }

    public Base36(List<int> positions)
    {
        this.positions = positions;
    }

    private List<int> GetPositions(string base36)
    {
        List<int> positions = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < base36.Length; i++)
        {
            positions.Add(letras.IndexOf(base36[i]));
        }
        return positions;
    }

    public static Base36 operator ++(Base36 a)
    {
        return new Base36(SumaUno(a.positions));
    }

    private static List<int> SumaUno(List<int> positions, int index = 0)
    {
        if (index >= positions.Count)
        {
            positions.Add(0);
        }

        if (positions[positions.Count - 1 - index] == letras.Count - 1)
        {
            positions[positions.Count - 1 - index] = 0;
            return SumaUno(positions, index + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            positions[positions.Count - 1 - index]++;
            return positions;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (int i in positions)
        {
            sb.Append(letras[i]);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    public static double ToBase10(string number)
    {
        double resp = 0;
        int contadorInverso = number.Length - 1;
        for(int i=0;i< number.Length;i++)
        {
            resp += letras.IndexOf(number[contadorInverso]) * Math.Pow(letras.Count,i);
            contadorInverso--;
        }
        return resp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Es exactamente la logica que estaba intentando aplicar, funciona, excelente.